# How to window/buffer IObservable<T> into chunks based on a Func<T>

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

Given a class:

```
class Foo { DateTime Timestamp {get; set;} }
```

...and an `IObservable<Foo>`, with guaranteed **monotonically increasing** `Timestamp`s, how can I generate an `IObservable<IList<Foo>>` chunked into Lists based on those `Timestamp`s?

I.e. each `IList<Foo>` should have five seconds of events, or whatever. I know I can use `Buffer` with a `TimeSpan` overload, but I need to take the time from the events themselves, not the wall clock. (Unless there a clever way of providing an `IScheduler` here which uses the `IObservable` itself as the source of `.Now`?)

If I try to use the `Observable.Buffer(this IObservable<Foo> source, IObservable<Foo> bufferBoundaries)` overload like so:

```
IObservable<Foo> foos = //...;
var pub = foos.Publish();
var windows = pub.Select(x => new DateTime(
    x.Ticks - x.Ticks % TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks)).DistinctUntilChanged();

pub.Buffer(windows).Subscribe(x => t.Dump()));  // linqpad
pub.Connect();
```

...then the `IList` instances contain *the item that causes the window to be closed*, but I really want this item to go into the next window/buffer.

E.g. with timestamps `[0, 1, 10, 11, 15]` you will get blocks of `[[0], [1, 10], [11, 15]]` instead of `[[0, 1], [10, 11], [15]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an idea. The group key condition is the "window number" and I use `GroupByUntil`. This gives you the desired output in your example (and I've used an int stream just like that example - but you can substitute whatever you need to number your windows).

```
public class Tests : ReactiveTest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var xs = scheduler.CreateHotObservable<int>(
            OnNext(0, 0),
            OnNext(1, 1),
            OnNext(10, 10),
            OnNext(11, 11),
            OnNext(15, 15),
            OnCompleted(16, 0));                  
            
        xs.Publish(ps =>                                // (1)
            ps.GroupByUntil(
                p => p / 5,                             // (2)
                grp => ps.Where(p => p / 5 != grp.Key)) // (3)
            .SelectMany(x => x.ToList()))               // (4)
        .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        
        scheduler.Start();
    }
}
```

#### Notes

1. We publish the source stream because we will subscribe more than once.
2. This is a function to create a group key - use this to generate a window number from your item type.
3. This is the group termination condition - use this to inspect the source stream for an item in another window. Note that means a window won't close until an element outside of it arrives, or the source stream terminates. This is obvious if you think about it - your desired output requires consideration of next element after a window ends. Note if your source bears any relation to real time, you could merge this with an `Observable.Timer+Select` that outputs a null/default instance of your term to terminate the stream earlier.
4. SelectMany puts the groups into lists and flattens the stream.

This example will run in LINQPad quite nicely if you include nuget package rx-testing. New up a Tests instance and just run the `Test()` method.

Comment: +1 Grouping is definitely a better way to do data-based windowing than my generalized solution. It doesn't always fit, but it works great for the specific requirements that were stated.

Answer (score 3):

I think James World's answer is neater/more readable, but for posterity, I've found another way to do this using `Buffer()`:

```
IObservable<Foo> foos = //...;
var pub = foos.Publish();
var windows = pub.Select(x => new DateTime(
        x.Ticks - x.Ticks % TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks))
    .DistinctUntilChanged().Publish.RefCount();

pub.Buffer(windows, x => windows).Subscribe(x => t.Dump()));
pub.Connect();
```

With 10m events, James' approach is more than 2.5x as fast (20s vs. 56s on my machine).

Comment: Interesting research on the time difference Alastair. +1

Comment: You should use the overload of `Publish` that has a `selector` parameter instead of using `RefCount`. It will also greatly improve the readability.

Answer (score 2):

`Window` is a generalization of `Buffer`, and `GroupJoin` is a generalization of `Window` (and `Join`).  When you write a `Window` or `Buffer` query and you find that notifications are being  incorrectly included or excluded from the edges of the windows/lists, then redefine your query in terms of `GroupJoin` to take control over where edge notifications arrive.

Note that in order to make the closing notifications available to newly opened windows you must define your boundaries as windows of those notifications (the windowed data, not the boundary data).  In your case, you cannot use a sequence of DateTime values as your boundaries, you must use a sequence of Foo objects instead.  To accomplish this, I've replaced your `Select`->`DistinctUntilChanged` query with a `Scan`->`Where`->`Select` query.

```
var batches = foos.Publish(publishedFoos => publishedFoos
  .Scan(
    new { foo = (Foo)null, last = DateTime.MinValue, take = true },
    (acc, foo) =>
    {
      var boundary = foo.Timestamp - acc.last >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

      return new
      {
        foo,
        last = boundary ? foo.Timestamp : acc.last,
        take = boundary
      };
    })
  .Where(a => a.take)
  .Select(a => a.foo)
  .Publish(boundaries => boundaries
    .Skip(1)
    .StartWith((Foo)null)
    .GroupJoin(
      publishedFoos,
      foo => foo == null ? boundaries.Skip(1) : boundaries,
      _ => Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
      (foo, window) => (foo == null ? window : window.StartWith(foo)).ToList())))
  .Merge()
  .Replay(lists => lists.SkipLast(1)
                        .Select(list => list.Take(list.Count - 1))
                        .Concat(lists),
          bufferSize: 1);
```

The `Replay` query at the end is only required if you expect the sequence to eventually end and you care about not dropping the last notification; otherwise, you could simply modify `window.StartWith(foo)` to `window.StartWith(foo).SkipLast(1)` to achieve the same basic results, though the last notification of the last buffer will be lost.

Comment: +1 for making me think harder about this whole class of joins. :-)